# C++ Winsock Accept Memory leak/Resource Leak

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, winsock

I have written a small test tcp listener. Said listener listens over port 28328 and works fantastic, expect for the huge resource/memory leak that happens every single time a client connects to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

SOCKET Socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

bool TestServer()
{
    WSADATA wsaData = { 0 };
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData))
        return false;

    sockaddr_in addr = { 0 };

    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    int Enable = 1;
    setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&Enable, sizeof(int));

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(28328);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(Socket, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr)))
        return false;

    if (listen(Socket, 50))
        return false;

    return true;
}


void Dolisten()
{
    if (TestServer())
    {
        sockaddr_in addr = { 0 };

        SOCKET Client_Socket = 0;

        int Lenght = sizeof(addr);

        for (;;)
        {
            Client_Socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

            Client_Socket = accept(Socket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &Lenght);

            if (Client_Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
                continue;

            printf("Client Connected %X\n", Client_Socket);

            shutdown(Client_Socket, 2);
            closesocket(Client_Socket);
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Dolisten();

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

While the original listener is much bigger than this and probably has a lot more problems which I haven't gotten to yet, as of right now this my biggest issue.

I assume that the issue occurs as a result of accepting of the socket and it not closing properly which then leaks to a handle leak. I base this on the fact that when I looked at task manager and other tools that monitor a process I can see the handle count increasing at the same rate as my connection happen.

Note:

1) By the looks of it the leak happens on the Non-Paged Memory.

2) This same snippet of code if compiled and used in a linux environment will not yield the same memory/resource leak.

3) I have compiled and tested this code on multiple windows machines and the same problem occurs.

4) (EDIT) I did see a couple of people with this exact problem posting on some of the MSDN forums and VS forums but all they were told to do was submit a ticket.

Comment: "This same snippet of code if compiled and used in a linux environment" Your code is WinAPI-specific and won't compile or run natively in a Linux environment.

Comment: @tambre I know, like I said on the post this is a test listener to post here, this is not the original code and the original code can be compiled on windows and linux.

Just keep in mind, even though this not the original code the issue still is present. Sorry for not being more specific.

Comment: @Asesh Yes, I did miss that here but I can assure you that the original code contains it on onexit

Comment: @Asesh Do you really believe the operating system isn't going to reclaim those resources when the app exits just because it didn't call `WSACleanup`?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Looks like the OS will do the clean up. Didn't see any memory leak even after not invoking WSACleanup

Comment: @Asesh Of course the OS will clean it up. it's not 1985 anymore.

Comment: @Asesh I see, well even if the OS didn't do the clean up after the application has exited the problem is still there. The non paged memory uses claims up like crazy every few hounded connection, it is as if I was never closing the sockets. The problem is that this same code works perfectly on a linux  environment (that is if changed to compile on one). Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the *client* is leaking sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no memory leak in the application you have shown.

Due to the way TCP/IP works, resources associated with closed connections can not be freed immediately. Packets may arrive out of order or be retransmitted after the connection has been closed. So even after a call to `closesocket` the actual OS socket remains open for a predefined amount of time (usually 2-3 minutes, can be adjusted with TcpTimedWaitDelay).

If you run `netstat -an`, you'll see a bunch of connections in CLOSE_WAIT or TIME_WAIT state:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:28328        127.0.0.1:56508        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:28328        127.0.0.1:56510        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:28328        127.0.0.1:56512        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:28328        127.0.0.1:56514        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:28328        127.0.0.1:56516        TIME_WAIT
  . . .
```

Of course (kernel) memory is needed to store these temporary states.

In addition, the TCP port number from the ephemeral range cannot be reused immediately, which means the *rate* at which you can open/close connections is quite limited.

Comment: I see now, in a way there is no solution to my problem since my application is supposed to hundreds of connections in a short mount of time which has caused me multiple blue screens due to the memory not being returned back quick enough. Well at least nothing i can do from what I see by your suggestion of modifying TcpTimedWaitDelay.

Comment: Also I see what you mean by  the ephemeral range, I will look into it a bit more (do some googling) maybe there might be something out of that rage that my help my situation a bit more. I will so try and change the value that you mention, I will report back with my findings.

Comment: @NotMyrealname Your  should also look into connection pooling.

Comment: If the machine is bluescreening, the problem is not in your code.  It is unlikely to be in Windows either.  More likely to be your anti-virus software, or perhaps a bug in the ethernet drivers.

Comment: Lowering the TcpTimedWaitDelay seems to have fixed my problem, also someone mentioned  that I should look into connection pooling which seems like a good idea. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The non-paged-pool is a kernel resource, and relates to memory which can not be paged by the operating system, and is a scarce resource.  So keeping an eye on it, is a good thing.

The fact it is in kernel, means the memory is not directly in your control.  It may be that the memory relates to un-sent, un-processed packets, which case the resource is the responsibility of your program indirectly.

Check for the handle leak - where that is coming from.  Application Verifier [Microsoft : Application Verifier download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028) can help identify the call stacks which are leaking memory and handles.